# How can I prove that this matrix is idempotent?

Tags: matrices, proof-writing, products, idempotents

I have the following matrix

$$A=\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & a & -b\\
-a & 0 & c\\
b & -c & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}$$

I have to prove that $M=A^2+I$ is idempotent knowing that $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$.

I can calculate M  using brute force as

$$M=
 \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & a & -b \\
-a & 0 & c \\
b &-c & 0
\end{array} \right)
%
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & a & -b \\
-a & 0 & c \\
b &-c & 0
\end{array} \right)
+
%
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array} \right)
$$

I obtain $$ M=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
c^2 & bc & ac \\
bc & b^2 & ab \\
ac & ab & a^2
\end{array} \right)$$

I have tried to solve this by brute force, but I cannot prove that $M=M^2$, that is what I need to show that $M$ is idempotent since my result by brute force contains too many terms to simplify.

Can someone explain to me how to do it?

Comment: Hint: $M=(c,b,a)^t (c,b,a)$

Comment: Even a direct computation immediately gives $M^2=M$ since $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$. There are only  a few terms to "simplify".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Giulio hint already solves the problem, but here's an alternative solution:

The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $x(x^2+1)$ meaning it has eigenvalues $0,-i,i$ and it is diagonalizable. Then $M = A^2+I$ has eigenvalues $1,0,0$ and it is still diagonalizable. This concludes that $M$ is idempotent